# Merge new value on Laravel array request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I have all my input values on `$request->input('users')` how can I merge new one?

Something like this:

```
$request->merge(['users.dob' => '2000']);
```

But obvious is not working.

Answer (score 8):

First, we need to get all items that belong in that array and save temporarily.

For instance,

```
$users = $request->users;
```

This way, you can access a user's data like `$users['name']` or `$users['surname']`.

Next, update or add whatever data you need to. For instance, like this:

```
$users['dob']  = "2000";
$users['name'] = ucwords($request->users['name']);
...
```

When we are done, we merge our temporary array back into `$request` like this:

```
$request->merge(['users' => $users]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$originalInput = $request->input('users');
$defaultValue = [
    'dob' => 2000
];
$mergedResult = array_merge($defaultValue, $originalInput);
$request->merge([
    'users' => $mergedResult
]);
```

If you're looking for something more elegant (read: hard way) and improve the reusability of your code, you can follow this steps:

1. Create a Service Provider, here we register a macro to `Request` object.

```
php artisan make:provider RegisterMergeInputRequestMacro
```

2. Write your provider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RegisterMergeInputRequestMacro extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        Request::macro('mergeInput', function (string $name, array $defaultValue) {
            $this->merge([
                $name => array_merge($defaultValue, $this->input($name))
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

3. Register the `ServiceProvider` in your `config/app.php` file:

```
return [
    ...
    'providers' => [
      ...
      App\Providers\RegisterMergeInputRequestMacro::class,
      ...
    ],
    ...
];
```

4. Use it like a boss:

```
$request->mergeInput('users', [
    'dob' => 2000
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$request->request->add(['users.dob', '2000']);
```

It seems `merge()` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data= $request->input('users');
$data['dob'] = 2000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for

```
public function __construct(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $request->request->add(
   ['date_of_birth' => implode('-',$request->only('year', 'month', 'day'))]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$request->request->add([
      'new-field1' => 'value 1', 
      'new-field2' => 'value 2'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the best solution I have come to so far.
let's assume you want to modify the **cover_image** name from request.

1. store all the form request in a variable

   ```
   $requestData = $request->all();
   ```
2. modify the array like this

   ```
   $requestData->cover_image = "your new image name";
   ```
3. save your data

   ```
   $requestData->save();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you make it an array, it will work.

```
$request->merge([
    'users' => [
        'dob' => '2000'
    ],
]);
```